# Reading a multimap<int, string> from a file

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need to read a `multimap<int,string>` from a file and i can't figure out how to do it.

```
ifstream in ("words.txt");
multimap<int, string> words;
int count = 0;
while (!in.eof()) {
        getline(in, words[count]);
        count++;
}
```

When i run it i get this error `error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::multimap<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘int’)
   getline(in, words[count]);`
I tried with `in >> words[count]`, and it doesn't work too. How should i fix this ?

Comment: Not directly related to your error, but before it bites you : [do not use `eof()` as a loop condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: a) dont use while (!in.eof), google it youll find an answer on stackoverflow b) multimap [doesnt seem to have that operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multimap` doesn't have `operator[]`.

You can use the `insert` method of `multimap`, or `emplace` if you use C++11.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/emplace) for emplace documentation and example.

Answer (score 0):

Use .insert() method:

[cplusplus reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/insert/)

Also if you want each pair at subsequent index you might want to use std::vector and push_back()

Answer (score 0):

There is no `[]` operator for `std::multimap`.
You must read a line as a string and then use `insert`.